# Using Method of Distribution

Tags: probability

We went over this in class but I didn't completely grasp the understanding for using the method. 
So I'm not sure if I did this properly. 
Given a pdf

$$
f_x(x) = 2(1-x)
$$
Find the density function of $$Y=2X+1$$

$$P(Y<y)=(2X+1<y) = P(X < (Y-1)/2$$
$$F_y(y)=2((y-1)/2) - ((y-1)/2)^2 $$
$$F_y(y) = (y-1) - (1/4)(y-1)^2 $$
$$\frac{d}{dy}F_y(y) = 1-\frac{1}{2}(y-1) = \frac{3-y}{2} $$

I really don't understand the intuition behind this. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with trying to find the CDF of $Y$, so we get 
$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y < y) = P(X < \frac{y-1}{2}) = F_X \left(\frac{y-1}{2}\right)
$$
This basically establishes the relation between the two CDFs, $F_Y$ and $F_X$.  Now, for $f_x(x)$ to be a pdf there was probably the restriction that $0 \leq x \leq 1$ (this makes its CDF integrate to $1$). By definition of a CDF we have 
$$
F_X \left(\frac{y-1}{2} \right)  = \int^{(y-1)/2}_0 2(1-x) dx  = 2((y-1)/2) - ((y-1)/2)^2
$$
where $(y-1)/2 \leq 1$. Notice that the integral is from $0$ instead of $-\infty$ because of the restriction on $x$.

So now that you have the CDF, it simply remains to differentiate it to get the pdf